# Background thread completion blocks possibly firing before completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks

I am writing a photo upload queue manager.

Here is my process. The user can take a picture or choose one from the camera roll.
The image, along with some other string data, is placed in queue. 
The queue is simply an array that contains the image path string and the other string data. The 'queued' image is saved to the documents directory of the application for later retrieval.

Every second the queue is checked to see if any images that need to be uploaded, then it does so, one-by-one.

When it uploads, the server responds with a string of `success`, if `success` then the picture is removed from list queue, the temp image is deleted and the program moves on to the next queued image.

If I call the `uploadImage:` method independently and pass it the image and string data, the image uploads fine. But when called from a background thread, the image is never truly uploaded even though the server responds success instantly. I feel like since the server is responding instantly with success, that the image is only partially being uploaded.

`processImage:` is the method that calls `uploadImage:` from the background.

I could really use an expert's eyes to see what might be causing the app to not fully wait on the photo to upload before continuing.

```
@interface ImageUploader ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * arrPhotoQueue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* timerUpload;
@end


@implementation ImageUploader {
    NSUserDefaults * defaults; //Just were we are currently storing a list of images.
    NSArray *paths;
    NSString *documentsDirectory;

}

#pragma mark Public Methods

- (void) startPhotoUploadCheck {
    if (!_timerUpload) {
        if(![_timerUpload isValid]){
           _timerUpload = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_timerCheckInterval target:self selector:@selector(checkForPhotosToUpload) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }
    }
}


- (void) addImageToQueue:(UIImage*)image withCallKey:(NSString*) callKey {


    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[self randomStringWithLength:8]];
    NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSMutableDictionary * data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [data setValue:fileName forKey:@"imagePath"];
    [data setValue:callKey forKey:@"callKey"];

    [_arrPhotoQueue addObject:data];

    if (![imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO])  {
        NSLog(@"Failed to cache image data to disk");
    }  else  {
        NSLog(@"Image %@", fileName);
        [defaults setObject:_arrPhotoQueue forKey:@"PendingPhotos"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    [self totalImagesInQueue];

}



- (void) checkForPhotosToUpload {

  //this does some logic to just see if there is a connection to the internet and that there are photos in queue then it calls
  [self proceedWithUpload];

}

#pragma mark Upload Image
- (int) removePhotoFromMemory:(NSString *) callKeyOfUploadedPhoto
{
    int nIndexOfUploadedPhoto = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < [_arrPhotoQueue count]; i++) {
        NSString * callKey = [_arrPhotoQueue[i] objectForKey:@"callKey"];
        if ([callKey isEqualToString:callKeyOfUploadedPhoto]) {
            //remove uploaded photo
            NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[_arrPhotoQueue[i] objectForKey:@"imagePath"]];
            NSLog(@"Remove image from queue: %@", [_arrPhotoQueue[i] objectForKey:@"imagePath"]);
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];

            nIndexOfUploadedPhoto = i;

            break;
        }
    }

    return nIndexOfUploadedPhoto;
}

- (void) proceedWithUpload {

    NSMutableArray* removeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_group_t taskGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    for (int i = 0; i < [_arrPhotoQueue count]; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(taskGroup);

        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[_arrPhotoQueue[i] objectForKey:@"imagePath"]];
        NSString * callKey = [_arrPhotoQueue[i] objectForKey:@"callKey"];

        [self processImage:image :callKey completed:^(bool bSuccess){
            if (bSuccess) {

                //photo is uploaded successfully
                int nPhotoIdx = [self removePhotoFromMemory:callKey];
                if (nPhotoIdx > -1) {
                    [removeArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nPhotoIdx]];
                }

                dispatch_group_leave(taskGroup);
            } else {
                dispatch_group_leave(taskGroup);
            }
        }];

    }

    // Here we wait for all the requests to finish
    dispatch_group_notify(taskGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // run code when all files are downloaded
        [self removePhotoFromQueue:removeArray];
    });

}

- (void) removePhotoFromQueue:(NSMutableArray*)index {

    NSArray *sortedIndex = [index sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
        if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            int nFirstIndex = (int)[obj1 integerValue];
            int nSecondIndex = (int)[obj2 integerValue];

            if (nFirstIndex > nSecondIndex) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            } else if (nFirstIndex < nSecondIndex) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }
        }

        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    for (int i =0; i < [sortedIndex count]; i++) {
        int nIdx = (int)[sortedIndex[i] integerValue];
        [_arrPhotoQueue removeObjectAtIndex:nIdx];
    }


    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"PendingPhotos"];
    [defaults setObject:_arrPhotoQueue forKey:@"PendingPhotos"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

#pragma mark Image Processor

- (void) processImage:(UIImage*)image :(NSString*)callKey completed:(void(^)(bool bSuccess)) block{

    __block NSMutableDictionary * message;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        message = [self  uploadImage:image CallKey:callKey];
        [self  uploadImage:image CallKey:callKey];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ([[message objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
                block(true);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Somethign is wrong");
                 block(false);
            }
        });
    });

}

- (NSMutableDictionary*) uploadImage:(UIImage *)theimage  CallKey:(NSString*)callKey {


NSData   * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self  fixrotation:theimage], 90);
NSString * jsonString=  [JSONCommunicator buildJSONForImageUpload:[self  prepareDictionaryDataForUploadWithKey:callKey]];
NSURL    * uploadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:MYURL];

// create the URL
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uploadURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// just some random text that will never occur in the body
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// create data
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

// JSON part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"params\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// media part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UploadedFile\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:imageData];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// final boundary
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postBody encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"Image String: %@", s);

// add body to post
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

// pointers to some necessary objects
NSURLResponse* response;
NSError* error;

// synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }

// convert data into string
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"TOPS Response String: %@", responseString);

NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    return dictionary;

}
```

Comment: You haven't shared the one method that matters, `uploadImage`. At the very least, we need to know if you're using `NSURLConnection` (which will not work on a background thread unless special steps are taken) or `NSURLSession` (which you should be using anyway, now that `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated). Also, I would expect `uploadImage` to employ a completion handler pattern, so you know when the asynchronous network request is done.

Comment: I think you should try using NSOperationQueue: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/

Comment: Gotcha. I went ahead and added the code. The JSONCommuincator simply takes creates a JSON Serialized string.

Comment: You really should excise `NSURLConnection` as well as synchronous network requests, but that's a separate topic. What does `uploadImage` display for "Error" and "TOPS Response String"? Do those look reasonable? There's a lot of code here for us to decipher, so it might be more efficient if you watch the network request via [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or WireShark and see if the request looks well formed. These tools can be invaluable. Or, a little more cumbersome, single-step through the `uploadImage` and make sure the request body looks good. But you should narrow this down for us.

Comment: No Errors and the Response String is "Success" from the server. If I call the Upload manually, it works fine. It is only when it is called from this background thread that it fails, even though the server responds success.

Comment: Then you really need to examine the request more carefully and see if it's really well formed. I'm assuming it's not well-formed, but it's a bit much to ask us to go through all of this source code to try to track it down for you. But, Charles or WireShark can really make that much easier, so you can see where the request went wrong, if at all.

Comment: First, using a timer to poll the queue isn't very elegant. As Vlad suggested you can use an NSOperationQueue or even dispatch a task onto a background queue when you call `addImageToQueue`. Your biggest problem, however, is concurrent access to an NSMutableArray. This object is not thread safe, so you need to either @synchronise your updates or guard the access using a serial queue. Also the use of NSUserDefaults to persist your queue is fairly icky.

Comment: Why do you call `uploadImage` twice in a row?

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry that was copy and paste error.